# font-face font embedding very slow on firefox

Tags: firefox, fonts, font-face, embedded-fonts

the rendering of a custom font embedded with font-face is really fast on webkit-based browser, but very slow on firefox: it starts to render the text before the font is downloaded, then the font is "replaced".

anyone knows a really fast and clean solution to avoid the problem ?

really thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a bit of quick research on the topic (FOUT: Flash of Unstyled Text), there seems to be no solution to the initial load at the moment. It can, however be mitigated on later page loads by caching the font.

Read more here: http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/10/13/font-face-and-performance/

Anyway, since it **is** a CSS3 feature right now, and since all browsers are slowly working with performance and compliance with it, I'd imagine that in the future it'll gain more features, performance, and stability, but for now, we'll have to stick with what we've got.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem as well, the solution that I've decided to go with is enabling gzip to manage otf files. The following link was very helpful:

http://salscode.com/web-resources/gzip-ttf-otf